# Phonegap Application does not run

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Android Phonegap 1.0.0 I want to redirect my application to open all external Urls in the same webview. I tried the following but it gives error.

`The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`

Where have I gone wrong?

My Code :

```
package com.phonegap.phonegapsample;
import com.phonegap.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class PhonegapSampleActivity extends DroidGap {

private WebView myWebView;
private WebSettings myWebSetting;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    //Get the Webview
    myWebView = super.appView; 

    //Get the WebSettings
    myWebSetting = myWebView.getSettings();

    //Enable Javascript 
    myWebSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Enable Zoom default : disabled
    myWebSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebSetting.setSupportZoom(true);              

    //myWebSetting.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    //myWebSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //myWebSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

} 

}
```

Comment: Why are you creating another web view under loadUrl?

Comment: don't try to make one more webview.try without creating the 2nd webview.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald @Subrat nayak I am not creating another webview. I am having another object `myWebView ` as a reference to the existing webview

Answer (score 0):

The error message says is can't load the initial index.html, it says nothing about external links, so I'd say you didn't put `index.html` in `/assets/www/` directory.

Comment: It works if I restrain till super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); in the onCreate Function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Restrain what? Please be more verbose. Also, do you want to open external links in a webview when user clicks on a link or from the start?

Comment: This works : http://tinyurl.com/cg8zm32 As the code says I am initially loading my `index.html` Now, This index can have viz 10 external links eg:-google.com. So For those requests I need to redirect to my existing webview

Comment: does [this](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/10/12/stupid-phonegap-tricks-loading-external-content/) solve the problem? (setting `loadInWebView`)

Comment: where to set the `loadInWebView` ?

Comment: Just before `loadUrl`, as it is described in the link above (click [here](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/10/12/stupid-phonegap-tricks-loading-external-content/)).

Comment: Yes this opens the Url in the same webview but I get a transition effect. Will check on my device and edit this answer accordingly

Comment: No The transition is still observed. Tested on Android Gingerbread 2.3.3

Comment: What transition effect? I would love to help you out, but it looks like your question does not provide enough information. Please edit it to provide: 1) minimal working example that shows a bug (hint: index.html is missing); 2) describe what you are trying to do; 3) outline steps that reproduce the error; 4) make sure your question is exact. Note that your comments do not make sense with the error message you supplied. Error message says that original `loadUrl` fails, NOT that it can't load external reference. As I said, I would love to help you, but you must give me a chance to do so.

Comment: I successfully upgraded my application to 1.9.0 which addressed all the above issues
@johndodo 
1)Okay I will upload the `index.html` file day after tomorrow when i go to office. As I am still interested to figure out the solution to the issue.
2,3,4)I want to open all the external URLS in same `WebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before **super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");**

```
this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
```

Comment: This solution is not working. And the url is observed to start in the new browser.